# save selected files in particular path

Tags: excel, vba

I want open file dialog box which allow me to select the multiple files. The selected files should be saved in particular path instead of opening. I am able to open the dailog box to select the files but not sure as to how to save in particular folder. Please assist.

```
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim i As Integer

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
    ).SelectedItems.Count
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
    ).SelectedItems(i)
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = strPath
    Next i
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.  Loop through the files that are selected.

Add tools pulldown select references,  pick "Microsoft Scripting runtime".

```
  dim fso as New FileSystemObject
  fso.CopyFile selectedFile, Targetfile
```